# Chef (ruby)- mount windows share, the slashes are backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

in Chef, I am running this command:

```
mount '/mnt/dir' do
   fstype 'cifs'
   options 'credentials=/etc/cifs_cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777'
   device '\\\\winServer.com\\dir\\folder\\subfolder'
   action [:enable, :mount]
end
```

I want the server mounted as
   //winServer.com/dir/...

But it is being mounted (in CentOs) as:

```
\\winServer.com\dir\folder\subfolder and
```

Ruby won't let me change the //s. Help, experts.

Answer (score 0):

Jollof - did you

```
 device '//winServer.com/dir/folder/subfolder'
```

?